# Recommend an IDE setup for CouchDB?

Tags: couchdb

I tried experimenting with CouchDB but I find that without syntax highlighting, code completion, auto indenting, and  other basic IDE features, I can't even code a Hello World.

What's the most common IDE set up, preferably integrated with eclipse?

Comment: "Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, [describe the problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/139399/) and what has been done so far to solve it." [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`erica` is a useful tool but it's not an IDE.

I finally settled on `KanapesIDE` as the closest thing to what I was looking for.

It is still very basic, a far cry from something like Eclipse, but good enough for quick experiments while learning CouchDB.

Comment: Kanapes IDE will hit 2.0 near time soon with support for OSX and Linux and gazillion of improvements.

Comment: Can you post a link to more info? I've found nothing about it except a Twitter post from 2012

Answer (score 2):

Apache CouchDB is made up of simple components: HTTP and JSON. There are plugins for Eclipse for both of these. The largest "helper" tool you'll benefit from having is a "couchapp" publishing tool.

The "couchapp" tools take a file system directory and serialize it into a JSON "design document" for Apache CouchDB (or Cloudant) databases to use for MapReduce, _show, _list, validate_doc_update, rewrites, etc.

The best one available at this time is `erica`: https://github.com/benoitc/erica

You can then build your design documents with any IDE or editor, and publish them from the command line using `erica`.

Hope that helps, Alex.

Comment: Thanks, I looked into erica, but eventually found KanapesIDE is more like an actual IDE.